# How to get the metadata of a file open in eclipse in a programmatic way?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I would like to get the metadata (creation time, last modified, size, etc.) of all the files that are open in eclipse in a programmatic way.

I have the code to get the list of files open in the eclipse editor, I want to know if I can get the metadata of each file along with it.

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

IEditorReference [] editors = page.getEditorReferences();
```

Comment: Because of the way `IEditorMatchingStrategy` is used when opening a file I don't think there is a way to get a complete list of files open in editors. Why do you think you need this list? There may be another way of doing what you want.

Comment: @greg-449, I do not want it as a list per se. I want to keep track of the creation time and access time of each file. Sambit 's solution worked for me.

Comment: If you want to know when files are changed in Eclipse use an `IResourceChangeListener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code, I provide below the pseudo code for you.

```
    IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

    IEditorReference [] editors = page.getEditorReferences();

    for (IEditorReference editorReference : editors) {
                try {
                    IEditorInput editorInput = editorReference.getEditorInput();
                    if (editorInput instanceof IFileEditorInput) {
                        IFileEditorInput fileEditorInput = (IFileEditorInput) editorInput;
                        IFile file = fileEditorInput.getFile();

                        //Once you get the file, convert it into java.io.File and you can get all the metadata from file
//Write your own logic to print and to check



                    }
                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

     }
```

Comment: Check and let me know about it.

Comment: This will work OK for the editors which use IFileEditorInput, but some editors use IURIEditorInput. Others like the plugin.xml/manifest.mf/build.properties editor edit multiple files.

Comment: @Greg Sir, I know you, I have learned many things from you about Eclipse plugin development. If you suggest or modify the code, it will be a good learning for us.

Comment: @Sambit, it worked fine. I converted the `IFile` to `java.io.File` and used `BasicFileAttributes` to get the required metadata. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @greg-449 Sorry, I do not understand. The files in question here are Java files.